# Early 2013 Macbook Pro with 4K: Picture quality?

Tags: macbook-pro, display, screen, resolution

This is sort of related to [this question](https://apple.stackexchange.com/questions/129653/early-2013-macbook-pro-with-4k). The 13.3 inch Early 2015 Macbook has a resolution of `2560 x 1600`. I'm not an expert on displays, I've done a lot of Googling but don't seem to understand.

How does my Retina Display with resolution `2560 x 1600` show up on a 4K screen with resolution: `4096 × 2160` in terms of quality of image? What will the pixel density on my monitor? Let's say the monitor I'm after is specifically this: `BenQ EL2870U 28 inch 4K HDR10 Gaming Monitor, UHD 3840x2160, FreeSync, 1ms Response Time, Eye-Care, Brightness Intelligence Plus, HDMI, DP, Built-in Speakers`.

1. Is my picture quality going to be fantastic? Or am I making a mistake trying to fit `2560 X 1600` into `4096 X 2160, 27 inches` and it's going to be super grainy with me being able to distinguish between pixels?
2. What are the monitor specifications that I should be looking for to get the BEST picture quality
3. Assuming that I may upgrade my laptop and simply end up getting a CPU later on in the future, and money isn't my biggest concern, can I just get a 4K monitor and downscale the monitor's resolutions to `2560 X 1600`?

The purpose of buying the monitor is not primarily gaming per say, but I would love to get the same FPS that I can on my laptop when playing Dota 2 and less lag during the data transfer from HDMI or whatever appropriate cable. My laptop supports Thunderbolt 2.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

From [Everymac](https://everymac.com/systems/apple/macbook_pro/specs/macbook-pro-core-i7-2.7-15-early-2013-retina-display-specs.html)

> This model supports a simultaneous maximum resolution up to 2560x1600 on two external displays via Thunderbolt. Alternately, it can support a single display up to 2560x1600 via Thunderbolt and a single display up to 1920x1200 via HDMI.

2560x1440 native on a 27" screen is just fine for my old eyes - I've got 2 of them here (screens **and** eyes ;) so 2560x1600 ought to be OK, assuming it scales down nicely.

"Best" picture quality would theoretically be a native resolution of that, not scaled - but that wouldn't be future-proof; so you'd have to make that call.

Comment: So get a 4k monitor, downscale resolution ON THE Monitor to `2560x1440`. If happy, keep it, else return the monitor

Comment: Downscale in the Displays CP; the rest, yup ;-)